# How to sort values in the same object that are in another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

I already sorted objects by pushing them in an array, but I am not sure on how to do the same, cleanly, in this situation (values in the same object in an object, in another object).

I'd like to sort by `start_date`.

I have **this object:**

```
{ '232250442': // id
  { '0': { start_date: '17:00', end_date: '19:00' },
    '1': { start_date: '09:30', end_date: '12:15' },
    '2': { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' },
    title: 'Mme',
    first_name: 'Caroline',
    last_name: 'X' },
  '241702607': 
  { '0': { start_date: '17:30', end_date: '19:30' },
    '1': { start_date: '11:30', end_date: '14:30' },
    '2': { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' },
    title: 'Mme',
    first_name: 'Malika',
    last_name: 'Y' },
  '249679103': 
  { '0': { start_date: '10:00', end_date: '12:00' },
    '1': { start_date: '16:30', end_date: '18:30' },
    '2': { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' },
    title: 'M.',
    first_name: 'Magellan',
    last_name: 'Z' },
  ...
}
```

**Result wanted:**

```
{ '232250442': 
  { '0': { start_date: '09:30', end_date: '12:15' },
    '1': { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' },
    '2': { start_date: '17:00', end_date: '19:00' },
    title: 'Mme',
    first_name: 'Caroline',
    last_name: 'X' },
...
```

`start_date` is a `moment()` object with `HH:mm` format.
Do you have any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: you have to implement the way to retreive them ordered when you need it, and you'll need an array at one point. something like getting `Object.keys(objVar)`, ordering it by value and such

Comment: Would it not be more cleaner if you have put these objects in an array and use `periods` as key instead of `'0'` or `'1'` or ... ? Are there always 0->2 or not ?

Comment: @Kaddath: I think you're right I can do it this way yes, just not sure about how to loop to have this object back after

Comment: @KarelG: Ah maybe, it's because on remote API I get these objects with indexes, so I did the same on this object to be cleaner, and it allows me to loop on it after easily with a simple for

Comment: @PierreHofman actually what i am saying is that if you want to keep it as an object, you will have to use the sorting method each time you want an ordered process (display, loop, etc). But you can go on accessing values from your original object (the sorting method would just provide you an ordered keys array that you can loop on, then you can use the keys on the original object). If you don't mind keeping your original object as it is, better transform it in an array first and use this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your suggestions, I reworked a bit my objects.

To explain a bit, I receive users' interventions from a remote API under objects form:

```
// myTeam object
{
  ...
  'id_employee': '287607426'
  'title': 'M',
  'first_name': 'User first name',
  'last_name': 'User last name',
  ...
}
```

And from another call, with the id_employee received in previous call:

```
// employeePlanningByDay object
'0': {
  ...
  'start_date': 'YYYYMMDDHHmm',
  'end_date': 'YYYYMMDDHHmm',
  ...
}
```

Here is the new object I obtain after my rework:

```
{ '287607426':
   { interventions: [
     { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' },
     { start_date: '09:30', end_date: '12:15' },
     { start_date: '17:00', end_date: '19:00' }
   ],
   title: 'Mme',
   first_name: 'Caroline',
   last_name: 'X' },
...
```

To obtain this, here is the full function code I use (I preferred to keep the loops so you can understand better what I do):

```
const getCommunityWorkingHoursByDay = async (session, dayChosen) => {
  const myTeam = await getTeamBySector(...); // Only my team, not all employees
  const lengthTeam = Object.keys(myTeam).length;
  const workingHours = {};
  // For all people in my team, get their planning, then return it as an object well formated for the bot
  for (const i in myTeam) {
    // Check for errors in bot's session
    if (myTeam[i].id_employee == session.userData.alenvi.employee_id && lengthTeam === 1) {
      return session.endDialog('Il semble que tu sois le premier membre de ta communauté ! :)');
    }
    if (myTeam[i].id_employee != session.userData.alenvi.employee_id) {
      const employeeId = myTeam[i].id_employee;
      // Get all intervention for an employee
      const employeePlanningByDayRaw = await services.getServicesByEmployeeIdAndDate(...);
      if (employeePlanningByDayRaw.body.status === 'KO') {
        throw new Error(`Error while getting employee planning by day: ${employeePlanningByDayRaw.body.message}`);
      }
      const employeePlanningByDay = employeePlanningByDayRaw.body.array_service.result;
      // Fill the object to return
      if (employeePlanningByDay) {
        workingHours[employeeId] = {};
        workingHours[employeeId]['interventions'] = [];
        workingHours[employeeId].title = myTeam[i].title;
        workingHours[employeeId].first_name = myTeam[i].first_name;
        workingHours[employeeId].last_name = myTeam[i].last_name;
        for (const j in employeePlanningByDay) {
          const interv = {
            start_date: moment.tz(employeePlanningByDay[j].start_date, 'YYYYMMDDHHmm', 'Europe/Paris').format('HH:mm'),
            end_date: moment.tz(employeePlanningByDay[j].end_date, 'YYYYMMDDHHmm', 'Europe/Paris').format('HH:mm')
          };
          workingHours[employeeId]['interventions'].push(interv);
          // Use lodash sortBy() to sort easily
          let sortedWorkingHours = _.sortBy(workingHours[employeeId]['interventions'], 'start_date');
          workingHours[employeeId]['interventions'] = sortedWorkingHours;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return workingHours;
};
```

And here it is. Perfectible, but it works ! Hope it can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist to sort parts of the objects, you could get first only keys with digits, sort them and take the inner data in an array for sorting.

After sorting reassign the values to the keys.

```js
var object = { 232250442: { 0: { start_date: '17:00', end_date: '19:00' }, 1: { start_date: '09:30', end_date: '12:15' }, 2: { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' }, title: 'Mme', first_name: 'Caroline', last_name: 'X' }, 241702607: { 0: { start_date: '17:30', end_date: '19:30' }, 1: { start_date: '11:30', end_date: '14:30' }, 2: { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' }, title: 'Mme', first_name: 'Malika', last_name: 'Y' }, 249679103: { 0: { start_date: '10:00', end_date: '12:00' }, 1: { start_date: '16:30', end_date: '18:30' }, 2: { start_date: '14:00', end_date: '16:00' }, title: 'M.', first_name: 'Magellan', last_name: 'Z' } };

Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    var keys = Object
            .keys(object[key])
            .filter(/./.test.bind(/^\d+$/))
            .sort((a, b) => a - b);

    keys.map(k => object[key][k])
        .sort((a, b) => a.start_date.localeCompare(b.start_date))
        .forEach((v, i) => object[key][keys[i]] = v);
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina ! I finally did it by myself, reworking the basic object as suggested